# htaccess rewrite folder with category and page id

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to be able to rewrite the url on my webpage so it also includes a category.

What I want is the URL to look something like this.

```
mypage.com/products/category/page
```

What I have now is a folder called products where I have an .htaccess file but I don't really understand how to use the variables to create something like above example. This is what I have right now.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-_]+)/?$^([a-z0-9-_]+)/?$ ../product.php?pageslug=$2&categoryslug=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is not correct as you cannot use `^` and `$` in the middle of your pattern.

You can use this rule inside `products/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ /product.php?pageslug=$2&categoryslug=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This will rewrite

```
mypage.com/products/category/page
```

to this URL:

```
mypage.com/product.php?pageslug=page&categoryslug=page
```

If your `product.php` reside inside `products` folder then use rule as:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ product.php?pageslug=$2&categoryslug=$1 [L,QSA]
```